# Find out what Windows 7 Firewall is blocking to prevent Client / Server communication

Tags: windows-7, firewall

I have a client / server application and both client and server are on windows 7.
If I disable the firewall on the pc acting as a server everything works great but if I enable it back the client is not able to connect anymore.
I'd like to find out what I have to allow on windows firewall settings but I have no clues about what's being blocked and why.
Also enabling the whole traffic coming and going to a certain ip would be acceptable as a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the client/server application?  Is it something you bought, or someone wrote custom?

Comment: Someone wrote custom...
That's my problem.
I don't know what are the process / services involved...
And windows 7 firewall won't give any kind of feedback after blocking :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to shutdown the firewall,
then use the "netstat" command to see which ports its using,
then open them in the firewall.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat

EDIT:
another option would be to use sysinternal's TCPview
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437

Comment: glad it helped, ran into a similar issue a few weeks ago